# mysql 5.6.40 and max_cache_size when You have a lot of RAM

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration

I have MySQL 5.6.40 and about 12 GB RAM and 24 cores (but there is also Apache+FPM threads so for MySQL left about 6 GB).

There are mostly MyISAM tables, but there also a few InnoDB.

At begining i had this configuration

```
key_buffer_size               = 256M
sort_buffer_size              = 1M
read_buffer_size              = 1M
join_buffer_size              = 1M
thread_stack                  = 192K
thread_cache_size             = 8
tmp_table_size                = 64M
max_heap_table_size           = 64M
myisam-recover                = BACKUP
max_connections               = 200
wait_timeout                  = 1200
query_cache_type              = 1
query_cache_min_res_unit      = 2k
query_cache_limit             = 4M
query_cache_size              = 512M
table_open_cache              = 5000

innodb_buffer_pool_size       = 2048M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances  = 8
```

Unfortunatelly sometimes for a short moment (only when there are a lot of bulk operations like import or recalculating) there is mysql slowdown. Using RAM is quite stable, but CPU using increases.

Tuning Primmer says that `query_cache_size` shouldn't be larger than 128MB. But what if I have a lot of RAM, and there is `Query cache efficiency: 79.5% (720M cached / 906M selects)`? Should I set lower query cache size and limit to increase performance?

---

Now I've got more RAM (24 GB) and cores (32 cores) and I want to use it for MySQL optimization. So I want to change configuration as below:

```
key_buffer_size               = 256M
sort_buffer_size              = 1M
read_buffer_size              = 1M
join_buffer_size              = 2M
thread_stack                  = 192K
thread_cache_size             = 8
tmp_table_size                = 64M
max_heap_table_size           = 64M
myisam-recover                = BACKUP
max_connections               = 300
wait_timeout                  = 1200
query_cache_type              = 1
query_cache_min_res_unit      = 2k
query_cache_limit             = 4M
query_cache_size              = 512M
table_open_cache              = 5000

innodb_buffer_pool_size       = 2048M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances  = 10
```

- `join_buffer_size` - form 1M to 2M because tuningprimer says that there are not indexed joins, so till i'll found them then there will be larger buffer fot that (final plan is add missing indexes for those joins)
- `max_connections` - from 200 to 300 because tuningprimer says that highest connection usage exceeds max_connection; it also increase memory usage by MySQL
- `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` - from 8 to 10 because i want to allow MySQL to use more available RAM and cores

**Questions are:**

1. If those settings makes sense/are optimal?
2. What about too much query_cache_size and limit when You have a lot of RAM?
3. Why there sometimes increase CPU load but not RAM?

Comment: Be aware that some details of the answer to your question profoundly depend on the version of MySQL / MariaDB you use. The version you used reached the end of support on 1-Feb-2021. Bluntly, why waste good and expensive hardware on an obsolete version of software?

Comment: This question would be a better fit on [dba.se]

Comment: @O.Jones Version od mysql not depends on me. I have plans to migrate onto 8.x version, but it needs application modifications and tests.

Answer (score 0):

When *any* modification to a table occurs, *all* references to that table are purged from the Query Cache.  The bigger the cache, the longer that takes.  Hence is it counterproductive to increase the size of the QC.  (I say no more than 50M, but that is rather arbitrary.)

Large queries on large tables using MyISAM block all other accesses to the table.  This *may* be causing your performance problem.  Changing to InnoDB is likely to decrease the conflicts between connections.

Use the slowlog (with `long_query_time = 1`) to help you find the slow queries.  Then, let's focus on improving them.

When "too many" connections are actively performing queries (see non-Sleep processes in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "Threads_running"`) the threads will be stumbling over each other and everything will take longer to finish.  Your "high CPU" is consistent with this situation.

RAM usage grows until it hits pre-determined limits -- primarily the main caches: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `key_buffer_size`.  After that, it fluctuates slightly as threads, buffers, etc, come and go.

Meanwhile, I/O is heavy if the tables don't fit in cache; light if they do.  CPU is heavy for complex queries that hit lots of rows.

For 24GB of RAM (that is mostly available to MySQL) and a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM, I would use

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
key_buffer_size = 2G
query_cache_size = 50M
```

That advice applies to most versions of MySQL and MariaDB.  However, MySQL 8.0 has disabled the QC and is working on getting rid of MyISAM.